# Using PHP to filter page render with user security levels, but disable links for non-privileged users

Tags: php, html, security, user-interface, mysqli

#### Background

I am developing a web application which has users classified by security levels 1-5.  This should act as the systems primary access level to allow users to view (or not) sensitive information.

On the system administration page I have a pretty basic page layout... i.e.

```
<?php if ($seclvl > 4) { ?>
// basic user code
<? } elseif ($seclvl > 1 && $seclvlv <= 4){ ?>
/// elevated privileges code
<? } elseif ($seclvl == 1) { ?>
// super administrator code
<? } else { ?>
//fallback if no security flag - error msg
<? } ?>
```

What i'm running into is figuring out the best methodology to have the system display a couple buttons in sec lvl 2-4, but yet only be able to be clicked by #1, without having to specify individually through php `display gray for sec lvl 2-4, activate lvl 1`...  Can anyone suggest a better methodology than the following:

```
<? } elseif ($seclvl > 1 && $seclvlv <= 4){ ?>

   <? if (!$seclvl == 1) { ?>
     <a href="#" class="disabled-add">Add a User</a>
   <? } else { ?>
     <a href="#" class="active-add">Add a User</a>
   <? } ?>

   //basics for seclvl 2-4... i.e:
   <a href="#" class="view">View User Info</a>     

<? } else { ?>
```

Furthermore, now that i'm writing this block of code (still untested, yet theory is there)...  i'm thinking that my short tag nested if statements wont actually work...  Any comment welcome.

I really *really* dont want to have to specify the conditions of security access for *each friggin link/button*.

Comment: @scott I appreciate the input but unfortunately I am building the system off of pure html, php and mysql.  I dont think I can implement a mariaDB plugin at this time, as this project is well overdue as is...

Comment: That was postgresql actually, but I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to make it easier or use `in_array()` like this:

```
<?php

if (in_array($seclvl, [2,3,4])) {  // seclvl is between 1 and 5
    // do something
}
```

... or as a function like this:

```
<?php

is_between($seclvl, $min = 1, $max = 5)) {
    if ($seclvl >= $min && $seclvl <= $max)
       return true;    
    return false;
}
```